# Is there a way to include hyperlink to some external HTTP URL in Scaladoc?

Tags: scala, url, scaladoc

Using Scaladoc, is there a way to include hyperlink to some external HTTP URL ?

using Javadoc this was easy.. but I am having trouble figuring out the syntax for Scaladoc.  I looked here: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Writing+Documentation, but came up dry.

Say I want to link to an external resource like this > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aardvark <  in my documentation.  What is the markup I should use ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try this :

> External links: [[http://scala-lang.org Scala web site]] becomes Scala
>   web site. The URL part must start with a scheme name (like http:) and
>   must not contain white space. The name part (Scala web site) is
>   optional.

Comment: glad i asked this, 'cause i forgot ;^) and this reminded me. Love stack overflow !